# How to load CSV files consisting of key:value pairs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm quite new to python and are working with Dataframes from .csv files. This has always worked fine, but i have now spent hours with one csv file i cannot load. Trying approaches from similar problems on Stackoverflow provided no solution so far. The file is separated by semicolons, but using a semicolon as a delimiter returns the  `ParserError: Expected 12 fields in line 11, saw 13`

To load the .csv file, i used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("ID_file_formatted.bed", delimiter=";", header=None)
```

To provide a sample of the file:

```
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000453935.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000453935.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-202;level=2;transcript_support_level=3;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000007990.1
ID=ENST00000440163.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440163.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-203;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346889.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000440163.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440163.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-203;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346889.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000455207.5;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000455207.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-204;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000007991.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000455464.7;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000455464.7;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-205;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346907.3
ID=ENST00000419160.4;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000419160.4;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-209;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346881.4
ID=ENST00000440038.7;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440038.7;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-210;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346880.3
ID=ENST00000423728.6;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000423728.6;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-212;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346879.2
ID=ENST00000616311.5;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000616311.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-213;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;tag=nested_454_RNA_Seq_supported;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000480470.2
```

I guess the problem is, that the lines are not of identical lenght and contain a different number of semicolons? 
I would like to end up with a dataframa that separates by ID..., gene_id.. and so on.
Any help is appreciated - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give me the top data set with the column names?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by top dataset - this file is a single column i extracted from a different file and wanted to split into different columns. Is that what you mean by top dataset? This looks like 

chr1 367711 367712 XPA_peak_331 7.79440 chr1 HAVANA gene 365389 522928 . - . ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7

Comment: Open the document in notepad++ and search for /n line separator is there in the line 11. Use this link as a tutorial [link](http://sql313.com/index.php/43-main-blogs/maincat-dba/62-using-notepad-to-change-end-of-line-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file is already organized as sets of `key=value` pairs, where you intend the keys to be your DataFrame labels, it would be simpler to convert it to a JSON representation and load it using [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Here's an example using your sample data:

```py
import json
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000453935.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000453935.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-202;level=2;transcript_support_level=3;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000007990.1
ID=ENST00000440163.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440163.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-203;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346889.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000440163.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440163.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-203;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346889.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000455207.5;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000455207.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-204;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000007991.1
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;level=2;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7
ID=ENST00000455464.7;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000455464.7;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-205;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346907.3
ID=ENST00000419160.4;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000419160.4;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-209;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346881.4
ID=ENST00000440038.7;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000440038.7;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-210;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346880.3
ID=ENST00000423728.6;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000423728.6;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-212;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000346879.2
ID=ENST00000616311.5;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;transcript_id=ENST00000616311.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;gene_name=AL732372.2;transcript_type=processed_transcript;transcript_name=AL732372.2-213;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;tag=nested_454_RNA_Seq_supported;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000002857.7;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000480470.2
"""

records = []
for line in io.StringIO(data):
    record = {}
    for field in line.split(";"):
        key, value = field.split("=")
        record[key] = value
    records.append(record)

df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(json.dumps(records)))
```

Which creates the following:

```
>>> print(df)
                    ID             gene_id  \
0   ENSG00000237094.12  ENSG00000237094.12   
1    ENST00000453935.1  ENSG00000237094.12   
2    ENST00000440163.1  ENSG00000237094.12   
3   ENSG00000237094.12  ENSG00000237094.12   
4    ENST00000440163.1  ENSG00000237094.12   
5   ENSG00000237094.12  ENSG00000237094.12   
6    ENST00000455207.5  ENSG00000237094.12   
7   ENSG00000237094.12  ENSG00000237094.12   
8    ENST00000455464.7  ENSG00000237094.12   
9    ENST00000419160.4  ENSG00000237094.12   
10   ENST00000440038.7  ENSG00000237094.12   
11   ENST00000423728.6  ENSG00000237094.12   
12   ENST00000616311.5  ENSG00000237094.12   

                             gene_type   gene_name  level  \
0   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
1   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
2   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
3   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
4   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
5   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
6   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
7   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
8   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
9   transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
10  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
11  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   
12  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  AL732372.2      2   

               havana_gene              Parent      transcript_id  \
0   OTTHUMG00000002857.7\n                 NaN                NaN   
1     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000453935.1   
2     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000440163.1   
3   OTTHUMG00000002857.7\n                 NaN                NaN   
4     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000440163.1   
5   OTTHUMG00000002857.7\n                 NaN                NaN   
6     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000455207.5   
7   OTTHUMG00000002857.7\n                 NaN                NaN   
8     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000455464.7   
9     OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000419160.4   
10    OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000440038.7   
11    OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000423728.6   
12    OTTHUMG00000002857.7  ENSG00000237094.12  ENST00000616311.5   

         transcript_type transcript_name  transcript_support_level  \
0                    NaN             NaN                       NaN   
1   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-202                       3.0   
2   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-203                       5.0   
3                    NaN             NaN                       NaN   
4   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-203                       5.0   
5                    NaN             NaN                       NaN   
6   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-204                       5.0   
7                    NaN             NaN                       NaN   
8   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-205                       5.0   
9   processed_transcript  AL732372.2-209                       5.0   
10  processed_transcript  AL732372.2-210                       5.0   
11  processed_transcript  AL732372.2-212                       5.0   
12  processed_transcript  AL732372.2-213                       5.0   

         havana_transcript                           tag  
0                      NaN                           NaN  
1   OTTHUMT00000007990.1\n                           NaN  
2   OTTHUMT00000346889.1\n                           NaN  
3                      NaN                           NaN  
4   OTTHUMT00000346889.1\n                           NaN  
5                      NaN                           NaN  
6   OTTHUMT00000007991.1\n   not_best_in_genome_evidence  
7                      NaN                           NaN  
8   OTTHUMT00000346907.3\n                           NaN  
9   OTTHUMT00000346881.4\n                           NaN  
10  OTTHUMT00000346880.3\n                           NaN  
11  OTTHUMT00000346879.2\n                           NaN  
12  OTTHUMT00000480470.2\n  nested_454_RNA_Seq_supported
```

Notes:

- Your data is already in a file so instead of using `io.StringIO()` in the `for` loop, you'll just use the file handle.
- If your data is too large to create a single object in memory within the `for` loop, you can progressively write each record to a JSON file and then load the file into a DataFrame

Comment: This was super helpful - now i have the dataframe that i want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no need to create the intermediary JSON representation, `df = pd.DataFrame(records)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `read_csv` method expects the file to be in a specific format. In this case each line MUST have the same amounts of semicolons, even when the empty for this attribute would be empty, e.g.

```
ID=ENSG00000237094.12;;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;
ID=ENST00000453935.1;Parent=ENSG00000237094.12;gene_id=ENSG00000237094.12;
```

Notice the *parent* field in the first row which needs to be initialized with an empty value. You can pass a specific value for those NaN values as a keyword-argument to read_csv (see documentation).

In order to load the dataset through `read_csv` in the future you should consider creating a new version in the format:

```
Name of col1; Name of col2; ...
<value1>; <value2>;...
```

This can be done with straight-forward python, reading and formatting each line individually.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to adjust the file then!